# Value change and retain base on input for table - Excel

Tags: excel

TO automate the quotation number base on date and identical.

if identical, quotation number will remain the same as previous line.
if un-indentical, quotation number will generate new.

excel macro code, but not sure how to solve with 2 unique situation.

- As identical input have 2 outcome:
  -> on the first line
  -> and on the 2nd and subsequent line

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula-

```
=A2&"/"&TEXT(D2,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&"/"&TEXT(COUNTA(UNIQUE($A$2:$A2&$C$2:$C2)),"000")
```

[image]